# Ignoring time zone in date object returned from an API using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm getting a response from an API containing a date in the following format `"/Date(1447773909000-0500)/"`

I have an angular filter that pulls out the timestamp:

```
.filter('formattedDate', function () {
    return function (posteddate) {
        if (!posteddate || !posteddate.length) {
            return;
        }
        return posteddate.slice(6, 19);
    };
})
```

When I display the date I use two filters, mine and the angular date filter to properly format it.

```
<span class="list-content col-sm-6">{{appointment.ApptDateTime | formattedDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a'}}</span>
```

The problem I'm having is the time is adjusting based off the users current time zone. I want to ignore this and instead use the value as it's returned with out altering it. I notice that depending on the timezone of the computer the response from the API changes the returned date. So instead of `"/Date(1447773909000-0500)/"` it will respond with `"/Date(1447914211000-0700)/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding following line in your WebApiConfig file.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling
= Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to make any changes like that in the API.